# Override mappings defined via annotation in persistence.xml

Tags: java, maven, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm new to JPA and EclipseLink as well and have the following situation:
I have Maven module where my entity classes are defined it's called **Model**. For defining relationships entity classes use annotations. Thus in persistence.xml  defined within **Model** there are no information related to relationships between entities. In some of the entities I have relationships with `EAGER FetchType` however in some cases it's not what I want. E.g. lets say I have an **Entity** with relationship **R**  where `FetchType = EAGER` and a maven module **X** that uses **Model**. In **X** I would like to use **Entity** with **R** but `FetchType = LAZY`. So in other words I need to override `FetchType` for **Entity**  in **X** somehow. I already investigated possible solutions and noticed that there are JPA annotations responsible for overriding the mappings between classes. However none of them allows to override FetchType

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem, why cant you use annotations like @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)?

Comment: Because in some of the modules I need lazy on that relationships as I don't need to fetch them

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use lazy loading by default fetch=FetchType.LAZY and you can add a method to your entity which loades them when you need them.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, however, some of the code already relies on the fact that relationships are defined as EAGER. I mean I have multiple modules that use Entity class. In some of them code is written with assumption that relationships are defined as EAGER so if I change them to LAZY I could potentially face a situation with LazyInitializationException.

Comment: EclipseLink doesn't throw the LazyInitializationException unless you are serializing the entity around so that the context is unavailable.  As long as it is available, it will load the relationship for you so you might not have an issue.  Going the other way, annotating with eager and then trying to force it to use lazy later isn't likely to work as it requires changes in the entity upfront to support lazy relationships - you've asked about this behavior in a number of different questions.